# How can I assign to a variable a value from a database table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

How can I assign to a variable a value from a database table in PHP. All I found didn't work at all. They were full of errors I try to fix them because that was old php code but I have at least one error left :(.

So I have a database named authentication, a table named users, a column from that table is called coins and I want to assign to a variable the value of coins from a specific username which I have on a global variable `$_SESSION['username']` for use in the `WHERE username = "'$_SESSION['username']'"` (username is also a column from the table).

Comment: Show what you've tried, we'll tell you where you're going wrong.

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: first u go through some tutorial

Answer (score -2):

```
$host = 'localhost'; //change it to your host
$dbname = ''; //your dbname
$username = ''; //mysql username
$password = ''; //your password

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql = 'SELECT coins
               FROM users WHERE username ='.$_SESSION["username"].' LIMIT 1';

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    //var dump row and see if it has require data or not, if it has, assign it the variable you want to use.
    var_dump($row);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Let me know if it was helpful. I did not test the code. but, it should work.

Good luck!

Comment: I just saw that . I don't think I did it or if I did it I pressed it by mistake cause I am new to stack overflow .. I didn't even knew this was a thing :). I am pressing the up thing and it says "Thanks for feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".. I didn't press the down button..

Comment: It says "C:\wamp64\www\it\logged\index.php:22:boolean false" I think I didn't do something right.. I it storing the value of "coins" to $row.. I am sorry if I am being dumb but I am a beginner. (I am bad at english too because English is not my main language)

Comment: Can I contact you by email?

Comment: @new_user: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You are already using a prepared statement - just bind the parameter and your code is secure.

Comment: @Pharaoh but it doesn't work for me and I don't even need not to be vulnerable .. I am doing this for a project.. I won't be hosting the website

Comment: Huh? It doesn't work for you? It's just one more line! I hope nobody else will ever be hosting this, too...

Comment: @AlexandruMarginean give me your mail address

Comment: @new_user alexmarginean16@yahoo.com